# nginx 0.7.65 rewrite not working for double slashes?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

Using Nginx 0.7.65, I spent a few hours trying to get what seemed to be a simple nginx rewrite to work. But the two forward slashes don't seem to work properly:

Url Before: http://www.testme.com/uploads//image.jpg

Url After: http://www.testme.com/uploads/300/image.jpg

I used the following rewrite section in my nginx.conf:

```
#try 1
location ~* \.jpg {
  (.*)//(image.jpg) $1/300/$2 permanent;
}
```

It didn't work. Any ideas how to get the nginx rewrite to properly work with two forward slashes? I tried escaping the slashes using // but that also didn't help at all. Should I try updating to nginx 0.8 and that should fix it?

I also tried these (each separately) and they didn't work. I get redirected to a 404 error page:

```
#try 2
location ~* \.jpg {
  rewrite "^(.*)([/]{2})image\.jpg$" $1/300/image.jpg permanent;
}

#try 3
location ~* \.jpg {
  rewrite (.+)//image\.jpg $1/300/image.jpg permanent;
}

#try 4
location ~* \.jpg {
  rewrite (.+)//(image.jpg) $1/300/$2 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `rewrite` module auto trim the slash when parsing the request. If you take a look at error log, you will see something like this:

*[notice] 5883#0: 1 "(.+)//(image.jpg)" does not match "/uploads`/`image.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server:  localhost, request: "GET /uploads`//`image.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"*

However, you can use [`$request_uri`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_uri) variable to keep the original request URI as received from client:

```
    location ~* \.jpg {
        if ($request_uri ~ "(.+)\/\/(.+\.jpg)") {
            set $folder_uri $1;
            set $file_uri $2;
            rewrite .* $folder_uri/300/$file_uri permanent;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex appeared to be wrong, as there are only 2 capturing groups. Try this:

```
(.+)//(image.jpg) $1/300/$2
```

I also made the * a + as you probably want *something* to be in front of the slashes.

Comment: good catch! I typed the regex out incorrectly. But when I was testing the regexes on the live server I did have it set up with the correct capture groups. Thanks for the suggestion to use the + instead of the * . I'll see if that changes anything.

Comment: nope doesn't work. i tried it exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: have you tried giving it the absolute path for the rewrite e.g http://hostname/$1/300/$2 ?